# TestNG groups in multiple suite xml files

Tags: xml, testng

I have my test suites set up in 3 different xml files, and two master xml files which call the other three.  The only difference between the two master files is one includes the "regression" group, and the other excludes it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="MasterSuite">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="regression" />
        </run>
    </groups>

    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="suiteFile1.xml" />
        <suite-file path="suiteFile2.xml" />
        <suite-file path="suiteFile3.xml" />        
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

However, the file which includes the "regression" group does not seem to be running the tests assigned to the group.  Does the  tag not apply to tests called from other xml files?  If not, is there a way to run the same set of tests (contained in multiple xml files) with or without a group?

Answer (score 0):

Does following code works for you?

```
<suite-files>
    <suite-file path="testng.xml">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <exclude name="regression" />
            </run>
        </groups>
    </suite-file>
</suite-files>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check:

1. If you have not forgotten to mark tests by groups as:

   @Test (groups={"group1"})

Do not forget {}, even if you have only one group.

2. If your master suite file is in the root folder of the module or project, where the test classes belong. Not in their children or parents!